# How to get the port numbers for a service - Docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to start containers with the docker-compose.yml. I am trying to start two services, one is **mongo** and other is **OHIF viewer**.

Currently I am able to access mongo locally (localhost:27017(after port-forwarding) in desktop whereas OHIF viewer isn't possible (ports aren't visible/empty so, I am not able to access them locally). Can you guide me as to how I can set them?

[image]

As you can see from my docker-compose file that I have set network_mode:"host" to be able to access them locally in my desktop as well.

Based on my json file, I thought the port was already set (pacsIP:8042) but it's missing as shown in screenshot above when I execute "docker ps" command. Can you guide me on this? I am new to docker and your inputs will definitely be helpful. PACSIP is my docker host (remote linux server) IP. I would like to port forward them and view it in my desktop

Please find below the **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3.6'
   services:
     mongo:
       image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: ohif-mongo
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"

   viewer:
     image: ohif/viewer:latest
      container_name: ohif-viewer
      ports:
        - "3030:80"
        - "8042:8042" - # Not sure whether this is correct. I tried with and without this as well but it didn't work
      network_mode: "host"   
      environment:
         - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/ohif
      extra_hosts:
          - "pacsIP:172.xx.xxx.xxx"
      volumes:
         - ./dockersupport-app.json:/app/app.json
```

As you can see that in the volumes, I am using a **dockersupport-app.json** file which is given below

```
{
   "apps" : [{
   "name"        : "ohif-viewer",
    "script"      : "main.js",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/app/bundle/",
    "env": {
    "METEOR_SETTINGS": {
              "servers": {
                "dicomWeb": [
                                    {
                    "name": "Orthanc",
                    "wadoUriRoot": "http://pacsIP:8042/wado", # these ports 
                    "qidoRoot": "http://pacsIP:8042/dicom-web", #these ports
                    "wadoRoot": "http://pacsIP:8042/dicom-web", #these ports
                    "qidoSupportsIncludeField": false,
                    "imageRendering": "wadouri",
                    "thumbnailRendering": "wadouri",
                    "requestOptions": {
                      "auth": "orthanc:orthanc",
                      "logRequests": true,
                      "logResponses": false,
```

How can I access the OHIF-Viewer locally? What changes should I make to docker-compose.yml or json file? I did with and without port 8042 under "Ports" section of docker-compose file but it didn't work still.

Comment: The way how I have represented "pacsIP:172.xx.xxx.xxx" is correct? or should it be pacsIP:"172.xx.xxx.xxx"?

Comment: I don't know it the docker-compose.yaml wrong because pasting here, but it seems to have a bad indention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `network_mode: host` it bypasses all of Docker's standard networking.  In this case that includes the port mappings: since the container is directly using the host's network interface, there's nothing to map *per se*.

`network_mode: host` is almost never necessary and I'd remove it here.  That should make the ports visible in the `docker ps` output again, and make the remapped port 3030 accessible.  As it is you can probably reach your service on port 80, which presumably the service binds to, directly on the host network.

Comment: Actually the docker is running in remote Linux server which doesn't have a UI. So, we port forward it to local windows system. If we don't set network=host, we aren't able to see anything locally. I am a beginner but I came to know from online that people do this when there is no internet in container.. We also face the same issue.  But how come other service alone is visible and port is accessible?  Can you help me understand what's happening?

Comment: I mean we are able to access mongo service locally whereas OHIF viewer service isn't accessible

Answer (score 2):

Did you use `docker-compose run` or `docker-compose up`?

According to [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/): "docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration."

Try to use docker-compose up command.

Comment: I used docker-compose up

Comment: Could you try to use another network_mode? It seems that host mode ignores port specified in dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks

Comment: If that's the case, then I shouldn't be able to port-forward mongo(port - 27017), because I am able to access them locally (localhost:27017) and get a valid message

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are trying to access mongo-db container - and you should be able to do this, however viewer is not accessible due to missing port-forwarding rules. So, in my previous comment I suggested to change network_mode from `host` to `overlay` to enable port-forwarding rules for the viewer as well. Host mode means that there is no isolation between local machine and container, and in your case - you should be able to access your viewer in local machine using port - 80.