# lynx:Unable to connect to remote host - Issue with Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, lynx

I am trying to start the below two services mongo and OHIF-Viewer as mentioned below in the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    mongo:
  image: "mongo:latest"
  container_name: ohif-mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"

  viewer:
 image: ohif/viewer:latest
 container_name: ohif-viewer
 ports:
  - "3030:80"
  - "3031:443"
 network_mode: "host"
 environment:
  - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/ohif
 extra_hosts:
  - "pacsIP:172.xx.xxx.xxx"
 volumes:
  - ./dockersupport-app.json:/app/app.json
```

As shown in the above docker file, I have two services. And when I do lynx localhost:27017, I am able to see that it returns valid result. whereas when I do lynx localhost:3030 or lynx localhost:3031, I get the below error message as

```
Looking up localhost first
Looking up localhost:3031
Making HTTP connection to localhost:3031
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost:3031/
```

Please note that based on some SO forum responses, I have already set export WWW_HOME=**"http://www.google.com/"** before issuing lynx command as well.

When I run the docker-compose file, the command executued successfully but I am not able to connect to lynx localhost:3031 or lynx localhost:30. How can I connect to these two ports?

Comment: This is the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522164/how-to-get-the-port-numbers-for-a-service-docker-compose-file): because you're using `network_mode: host`, the `ports:` are completely ignored.

Comment: But may I know how can I access port 8042? Actually there are two things in play here. One is port 3030 (OHIF) for the viewer and the other is 8042 for the explorer (orthanc). Port 8042 is mentioned in the docker file

Comment: @DavidMaze - Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610107/integrate-two-docker-apps-docker-compose-and-docker-run

Comment: @DavidMaze - If you can write as an answer for this post, I can mark it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your Docker daemon configuration (JSON)? - https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/